# Batch delete a large number of files

Tags: php, linux, unix, ubuntu

Everyday user-uploaded files older than a month are deleted from the server. User uploads are stored into directories by the day (eg `/var/www/media/2013-03-13`) so its easy to identify the files/directory that needse to be deleted.

**Problem:** Deleting 100,000 files at a time makes the server unresponsive and takes a long time. (Ubuntu 12.04 with 2x2TB ext4 SATA3 hdd in software RAID1). At the moment PHP is doing `exec` on the command `find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -delete`.

How do I split up the files required for deletion? Doing a `ls` will take really long on those large directories.

*Solution need not be in PHP. It does not even require splitting the files into smaller batches*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find the directories of the days you want to keep
2. Find the directories of all days
3. Remove 1. from 2.
4. `rm -rf` the directories you get from 3.

I'm not sure if this is faster than your method, but it avoids explicitly listing all the files in the directories.

Comment: I tried `rm -rfv dirname` and `find dirname -maxdepth 1 -print -delete` so both prints out the filenames as they delete. For both cases, the list of files being deleted is streamed to stdout, then it just hangs there. `df` shows no more files are being deleted.... until some time later, more files are shown to be deleted, then hangs again

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to read all the files, but to use `readdir` to get them one by one. See [Perl to the rescue: case study of deleting a large directory](http://blogs.perl.org/users/randal_l_schwartz/2011/03/perl-to-the-rescue-case-study-of-deleting-a-large-directory.html) for a Perl solution.